# VueJS errors when using external components

Tags: vue.js, components, vue-component, vue-good-table

Let me preface this by saying that I'm new to VueJS and I expect the solution to my problem is something trivial but I can't for the life of me figure it out or find it online so here I am :

I followed [Traversy Media's crash course on VueJS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qZXt1Aom3Cs) and built the task tracker app alongside him and everything was working well. But after the course ended, I decided to play around with Data Tables in the About page, specifically, using tables that have column filtering. Two candidates came up : VueGoodTable and VueBootstrap4Table.

I know for a fact that VueGoodTable works because I had already used it before with Laravel without really understanding how any of it works, but when I tried to import it here, I kept getting this error :

[image]

Code:

```
<template>
  <div class="about">
    <h1>This is an about page</h1>
    <vue-good-table
      :columns="columns"
      :rows="rows"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import 'vue-good-table/dist/vue-good-table.css'
import { VueGoodTable } from 'vue-good-table';

export default {
  components: {
    VueGoodTable,
  },
  data(){
    return {
      columns: [
        {
          label: 'Name',
          field: 'name',
        },
        {
          label: 'Age',
          field: 'age',
          type: 'number',
        },
        {
          label: 'Created On',
          field: 'createdAt',
          type: 'date',
          dateInputFormat: 'yyyy-MM-dd',
          dateOutputFormat: 'MMM do yy',
        },
        {
          label: 'Percent',
          field: 'score',
          type: 'percentage',
        },
      ],
      rows: [
        { id:1, name:"John", age: 20, createdAt: '',score: 0.03343 },
        { id:2, name:"Jane", age: 24, createdAt: '2011-10-31', score: 0.03343 },
        { id:3, name:"Susan", age: 16, createdAt: '2011-10-30', score: 0.03343 },
        { id:4, name:"Chris", age: 55, createdAt: '2011-10-11', score: 0.03343 },
        { id:5, name:"Dan", age: 40, createdAt: '2011-10-21', score: 0.03343 },
        { id:6, name:"John", age: 20, createdAt: '2011-10-31', score: 0.03343 },
      ],
    };
  },
}
</script>
```

This code is literally copy-pasted from the Get Started page of the VueGoodTable documentation.

A different error also happens when I try to use VueBootstrap4Table instead :

[image]

Code:

```
<template>
  <div class="about">
    <h1>This is an about page</h1>
    <vue-bootstrap4-table :rows="rows" :columns="columns" :config="config">
    </vue-bootstrap4-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import VueBootstrap4Table from 'vue-bootstrap4-table'

export default {
  data: function() {
        return {
            rows: [{
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": {
                        "first_name": "Vladimir",
                        "last_name": "Nitzsche"
                    },
                    "address": {
                        "country": "Mayotte"
                    },
                    "email": "franecki.anastasia@gmail.com",
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": {
                        "first_name": "Irwin",
                        "last_name": "Bayer"
                    },
                    "age": 23,
                    "address": {
                        "country": "Guernsey"
                    },
                    "email": "rlittle@macejkovic.biz",
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": {
                        "first_name": "Don",
                        "last_name": "Herman"
                    },
                    "address": {
                        "country": "Papua New Guinea"
                    },
                    "email": "delia.becker@cormier.com",
                }],
            columns: [{
                    label: "id",
                    name: "id",
                    filter: {
                        type: "simple",
                        placeholder: "id"
                    },
                    sort: true,
                },
                {
                    label: "First Name",
                    name: "name.first_name",
                    filter: {
                        type: "simple",
                        placeholder: "Enter first name"
                    },
                    sort: true,
                },
                {
                    label: "Email",
                    name: "email",
                    sort: true,
                },
                {
                    label: "Country",
                    name: "address.country",
                    filter: {
                        type: "simple",
                        placeholder: "Enter country"
                    },
                }],
            config: {
                checkbox_rows: true,
                rows_selectable: true,
                card_title: "Vue Bootsrap 4 advanced table"
            }
        }
    },
    components: {
        VueBootstrap4Table
    }
}
</script>
```

I'm guessing that I'm not importing these components correctly somehow, so I would appreciate any help with this.

Thank you.

Comment: Did the crash course cover installing these packages?  Usually it's done using "npm install".  Is that how you did it?

Comment: Yes, I did "npm install --save vue-good-table", "npm i bootstrap@4" and "npm i vue-bootstrap4-table --save" before trying any of these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unfortunate fact is that "not so recent" release of Vue v3 has bring some breaking changes from Vue 2 which require some [migration](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/introduction.html)

It is safe to say that very little of the existing components and component libraries created for Vue 2 work without any modification in Vue 3

The [repo](https://github.com/bradtraversy/vue-crash-2021/blob/master/package.json) linked to the course shows that you are using Vue 3. But Both the [vue-good-table](https://github.com/xaksis/vue-good-table/issues/758) or [vue-bootstrap4-table](https://github.com/rubanraj54/vue-bootstrap4-table) are Vue 2 components and do not have a version for Vue 3 yet

So you need to look for different component and look for explicit support of Vue 3...

Comment: I just tried with Vue 2 and they worked correctly, thank you. Should I only use Vue 2 for the near future ?

Comment: Vue 3 is great, you just need to be careful when choosing 3rd party components...